# How to add a Table View Controller to a tab based application Xcode 4.3.3

Tags: ios, templates, view, tabs, controller

So I initially started with the tab-based application template for iOS 5.
I've got a tab bar hooked up to two views, but when I go to add a Table View Controller to the firstviewcontroller, It won't let me.

I'm a little confused on how I should tackle this? Do I have to do it with code? Or is there a way I can graphically do this?
[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

View embedding in Storyboards isn't straightforward.

First, delete `First View Controller`:

[image: Storyboard without First View Controller]

Now, drag a new `Table View Controller` onto the storyboard:

[image: Storyboard with Table View Controller]

Finally, create a relationship between `Tab Bar Controller` and the new `Table View Controller`.

Select the `Tab Bar Controller` and then while pressing the `Control` key, drag your mouse over to the `Table View Controller` and let go with your mouse. In the popup box, select `Relationship - View Controllers`

[image]

And now the new `Table View Controller` should be a tab within the original `Tab Bar Controller`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I appreciate the time you took to take the screenshots!

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 8, the table view will become totally blue after the dragging and selecting Relationship. Just click at the bottom of the blue table view and select a `system item` in the `attributes inspector` and everything will be fine.